# "The current node list is empty." even though I've checked it

Tags: php, parsing, guzzle, goutte

I'm using Goutte to parse a website with pagination and I get in trouble after I get to the last page.

```
$as = $crawler->filter('tbody > tr > td > a');
if($as->count())
{
    $as->each(function ($node) use (&$URLs)
    {

        $URLs[] = $node->attr('href');

    });
}
```

I've tried checking with `empty($as)`, `$as->count() > 0`, but nothing seems to be working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your particular use case prevent you from using Client::links()?  What does the raw html look like for the page you are having problems with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer. I think my syntax was wrong. It works this way:

```
$crawler->filter('tbody > tr > td > a')->each(function ($node, $i = 0) use (&$URLs)
            {
                {
                    $URLs[] = $node->attr('href');
                }
            });
```